# Spring boot PathVariable not passed getting 404 URL doesn't exists

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, error-handling, path-variables

While creating a GET endpoint in a Spring web application I have a path variable(annotated with `@PathVariable`) passed to my API.

If I don't pass any value on path, the controller responds with HTTP 404 status.

**Endpoint:** **http://localhost:8080/observability-core/v1/systems/**

If I pass a value it responds as expected (e.g **http://localhost:8080/observability-core/v1/systems/123**)

If the path variable is missing on the request, I want to throw HTTP 400 Bad Request to indicate something like is not passed.

**PS:** - *when I hit request with above url I am not getting any logs implying no request reached the application. That could mean endpoint doesn't exists, which is misleading. How do I customise the error response in this case?*

Default response from Spring controller endpoint:

```json
{
    "timestamp": "2024-01-04T06:48:18.584+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/observability-core/v1/systems/"
}
```

Comment: You are getting this from spring itself, for bad request it should be a valid request first of all , what this error says is , the API you are invoking itself could not be found by Spring , hence you are getting 404 not found from dispatcher servlet

Comment: API consumer must know what endpoint he/she is consuming , for Bad request post hitting the correct end point, you must utilize spring annotations such as `@Validated` & `@Valid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My proposed solution:**

- Specify the path with and without the parameter: `@GetMapping(value = { "/path", "/path/{param}" })`
- Mark the Path variable as `required = false` (`@PathVariable(required = false) String param`
- handle the situation when parameter is missing and respond as required (with HTTP Status 400 in your case)

#### Minimalistic Example

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public class FooController {

    @GetMapping(value = { "/{firstParam}", "/" })
    public ResponseEntity<String> getFoo(@PathVariable(required = false) String firstParam) {
        if (null == firstParam) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("The first param is required");
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok("The first param is: " + firstParam);
    }
}
```

**A Test case:**

```java
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class FooControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void whenParameterIsPassesShouldReturnOk() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/foo/param"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string("The first param is: param"));
    }

    @Test
    void whenParameterIsNotPassedShouldReturnBadRequest() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/foo/"))
                .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
                .andExpect(content().string("The first param is required"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tamas Csizmadia.
your solution seems more logical and solves my issue.
Still have one doubt How can I generalize this behaviour for all of endpoints within my application having pathvariables. Can we think of any general handler to all this validations.

Comment: Dear @NitinGangwar - to be honest I rather handle these cases in a Service component and keep the Controllers as thin as possible. You can properly plan and design your Service classes with composition to have a common logic to handle parameters passed to your Services.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it done by following this approach.

```
 @RequestMapping("/observability-core/v1/systems")
 public class YourController {

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getSystemDetails(@PathVariable(required = false) String id) {
        if (id == null) {
            // Handle the case where the path variable is not provided
            return new ResponseEntity<>("ID not provided in the request.", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        // Your existing logic when the ID is provided
        return new ResponseEntity<>("System details for ID: " + id, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: If you don't specify the mapping without the variable notation, it will still respond with HTTP 404 (which is the expected behaviour from Spring's side, IMHO)

Comment: Hey Arslan, In this case request will never reach endpoint as spring treats it as a different url. Below tamas solution has extra check of empty url using that it works.